# Retrieve client side (html/ controller) data in server sider (express/ node.js)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am new to building applications using MEAN stack and am trying to build a website that queries programme data stored in a mongodb collection. Within my html index file I have implemented a search bar:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" ng-model="keywords">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ng-click="mongoQuery()"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

My controller.js file then initiates the call to the server to get all mongodb collections that match the keyword that was searched as such:

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.mongoQuery = function(){
    console.log($scope.keywords);
    $http.get('/search_results', $scope.keywords);
  }
}]);
```

I then attempt to retrieve all records that match the keyword (either through their tag field, or through their categories field) entered in the search bar in my server.js file as such:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mydb', ['bbctest']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// THIS FUNCTION DOES NOT WORK
app.get('/search_results', function(req, res){
  //console.log(req.body);
  console.log("I recieved a GET request for searching keywords")
  var searchKeywords = req.body.keywords;
  console.log(searchKeywords);
  db.bbctest.find( { $or: [ { categories:searchKeywords} , {tags:searchKeywords } ] },  { complete_title: 1 } ).forEach(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

I am trying to access the variable $scope.keywords from the controller but do not know how. As you can see above, I tried using **req.body.keywords** but that is returning an empty object when I use the search bar.

I would appreciate any help! Also if there are any useful resources out there that you guys would recommend that would help me build such an application (search engine) that would be great!.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use query param with get request to send params and value**

```
$scope.mongoQuery = function(){
    console.log($scope.keywords);
    $http.get('/search_results?keywords='+$scope.keywords);

   //when using post request use like below 
   // $http.post('/search_result',{keywords:$scope.keywords});
  }
```

**Add app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); before app.use(bodyParser.json());**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mydb', ['bbctest']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

//add below line
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//when using post request -> change app.get to app.post
app.get('/search_results', function(req, res){
  //console.log(req.body);
  console.log("I recieved a GET request for searching keywords")

  //var searchKeywords = req.body.keywords;  //when using post request 

 //accessing query parmas
  var searchKeywords = req.query.keywords; 

  console.log(searchKeywords);
  db.bbctest.find( { $or: [ { categories:searchKeywords} , {tags:searchKeywords } ] },  { complete_title: 1 } ).forEach(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

Comment: Ok I have done that. What about accessing the "keywords" variable from controller.js? It is still coming up as an empty var.

Comment: Yes that worked thanks. My mongodb query still does not work however, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You like to match exactly keywords or result that having tag and category like keywords ? @sums22

Comment: Match the word exactly.

Comment: It seems to have worked as I am getting results, but after I get results I then get this error:
/Users/ss/Documents/Back_End_Projects/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: it seems you are calling/executing res.json or res.send twice , please check this?

Comment: Yes you are right I think it happens when I use the search bar again to search for another item. I am going to accept your answer because it answers my initial question. But any idea how to step this new error from appearing when searching for a new item?

Comment: That wasn't case , when u search item again , this is because when u execute res.json twice in a single search request like  res.json(docs); and again res.json(docs). Try using res.end() after res.json(docs);